# Apache interpretando script python como arquivo

Tags: python, apache, aplicação-web

Estou montando um site e quero que ele rode um script python no action do html 
a questão é que meu navegador está interpretando o script como se fosse um arquivo.py para download

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cadastro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .menunav, .navbar-brand{
         color:white;

        }
        body {
        background-color:#e0e0e0;

        }
        #painel{
         width:30%;
        height:30%;
        margin-left:36%;
        margin-top:10%;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" >pyagenda</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="index.html" class="menunav">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="entrar.html" class="menunav">Entrar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="atualizar.html" class="menunav">Atualizações</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" id="painel">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
       Cadastro:
   </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="POST" action="cgi-bin/cadastrar.py">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Usuario:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="30" placeholder="Digite seu Usuario" name="usuario">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Digite seu Email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Senha:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="10" placeholder="Digite Sua Senha" name="pass">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nome:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="80" placeholder="Digite Seu Nome" name="nome">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script html

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import mysql.connector
#construtores do form html
cadastro = cgi.FieldStorage()
usu = cadastro.getvalue("usuario")
senha = cadastro.getvalue("pass")
em = cadastro.getvalue("email")
nome = cadastro.getvalue("nome")

#código mysql
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="root",password="root",host="localhost",database="agenda")
cursor = conn.cursor()

query =  ("""INSERT INTO cadastros
            (usuario,senha,email,nome)
            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""")
valores = (usu,senha,em,nome)
cursor.execute(query,valores)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

cadastrar.py

eu uso Ubuntu como sistema operacional

Comment: Você colocou o script como CGI?

Comment: O apache não interpreta diretamente qualquer arquivo executavel, a não ser que vá usar a "porta CGI" (geralmente é uma pasta com nome cgi-bin). Tem que configurar o httpd.conf. Diga, já ouviu falar de mod_wsgi?

Comment: Instale o [mod_python](http://modpython.org/)

Comment: Se você está fazendo no windows é mais simples é só configurar o httpd.conf.